# [T.[varcategory]] in mixedlm statsmodels.formula.api Results - What Does "[T.[this category]]" Mean?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Simple question - what does the category sitting after "[T." below represent in the model results from a mixedlm model using statsmodels?

Is that the reference category or the target (this variable "Period" contains two categories - "Pre" and "Post" so if it is the target, that means "Post" is the reference category)?

Thanks in advance!!

| blank | Coef. | Std.Err. | z | P>z | [0.025 | 0.975] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | -91.240 | 30.023 | -3.039 | 0.002 | -150.085 | -32.396 |
| C(Period)[T.**Pre**] | 23.988 | 5.034 | 0.773 | 0.040 | 14.812 | 36.837 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that does not appear in the summary is the base and the numbers for the other one show how different it is from that base or as you said reference, and if that difference is significant (which is significant here!).